# text content located in second br tag can't be printed

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I'm trying to print the text content located in second br tag by following xpath but all texts which are in all br tags are printed in console. What might be the reason ?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Telefon')]]")).getText();
```

[image]

Comment: If you inspect the page you can just right click the element and copy the xpath and use if  it is not under an iframe. h2/br[2] should be the xpath most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't get the text is because the text is not in the `br` tag.

`<` open `br` tag `/>` close

Additionally, if you [read a bit more about it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp), even the `/>` is surplus to requirements. If you had just `<br>` the text wouldn't be contained within it because:

> The `<br>` tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag.

The point is, all your text is h2. You need to deal with that the best you can.

To solve you're issue you'll need to:

- `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` - this will give you all the text of the `h2` with the `br` tag
- split your string on the string `<br>`  (please note that in chrome my `<br />` becomes `<br>` - ***you might need to adjust this***)
- select either select `item[2]` or do a lamda to select the item that contains your text (do whichever you feel more comfortable with)

And those steps look like this:

```
        //Get the element, 
        var h2Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Telefon')]]"));
        var myTextArray = h2Element.getAttribute("innerHTML").split("<br>");

        //approach 1 - just print the [1] item
        var approach1Text = myTextArray[2];
        System.out.println(approach1Text);

        //aproach 2 - use a lamda to select by contains
        var approach2Text = Arrays.stream(myTextArray).filter(a -> a.contains("Telefon")).findFirst().get();
        System.out.println(approach2Text);
```

---

For a bonus note - you probably had fun getting your xpath to work because the `br` tag splits the text into separate elements. As  result your `h2` actually has multiple `text()` values. It has `text()`, `text()[2]`, `text()[3]`, etc - as many as there are `br`s

I put together a simple page to test this for you - just to show you what's going on:  (note the xpath in dev tools)

[image: xpath]

This is `text()[3]` because xpaths are indexed from 1  (comapred to the java code above that starts at 0). However - that's just an example of why it's tricky, **i wouldn't recommend you do it that way**.

The easy way to eliminate the `<br>` (and other tags!) affect on text is to use `normalize-space()`.

An xpath like this works and is realtively simple to follow.

```
//h2[contains(normalize-space(),'Telefon')]
```

Maps to my sample page OK:

[image: good match on xpath]

I share this extra bit in case you have any more text-split objects and it helps you down the line.

...All that said - good work on getting your original xpath to work. That's good too.

Answer (score 0):

The driver.findElement() function returns all the elements with the given Xpath. To get only one element in selenium you can use **driver.find_element_by_xpath(fxp)** function, where 'fxp' is **full XPath** of the given element.

Comment: there seems no method as find_element_by_xpath in driver

Comment: You can see this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_xpath-driver-method-selenium-python/ to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
//h2/br/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'Telefon')]
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks but this error occurs; org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException.  The result of the xpath expression "//h2/br/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'Telefon')]" is: [object]. It should be an element.